# Unhandled rejection Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: node.js, object, express, reactjs, unhandled

In my Express, I set a router like this so that it will render component `Dashboard` on server-side:

```
app.get('/dashboard', auth.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        quotes.findAllByUser(req.user.id).then(function(result){
            var Dashboard=require('../component/dashboard.js').Dashboard;
            var DashboardHTML=ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
                <Dashboard user={req.user} list={result}/>
            );
            res.render('dashboard.ejs',{dashboard:DashboardHTML});
        });
    });
```

In my component `Dashboard`, written in React like this:

```
var React=require('react');
var CreateFragment=require('react-addons-create-fragment');

var Dashboard=React.createClass({
    render:function(){
        var children=CreateFragment({
            childUser:this.props.user,
            childList:this.props.list
        });
        return (
            <div classNameN="container">
                {children.childUser}
            </div>
            );
    }
});

exports.Dashboard=Dashboard;
```

Then I started server and entered browser in that route, and got this error:

```
Unhandled rejection Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {avatar, email, id, name, token, type}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Dashboard`.
```

If I try `console.log(this.props)` before returning `render` function, all objects are logged into console normally. But I can't render it. I thought I already wrapped `props` passed by router in fragment

Comment: Do you want to render a block of json? Why not iterate over the key/value pairs and display them somehow? I don't think using a fragment here adds any value.. better to be more explicit about how you want to display your object.

Comment: @azium How could I do that? Then I want to map each item in `list` then display all of them

Comment: `Object.keys(children.childUser).map(key => <div>{ children.childUser[key] }</div>)`

Comment: @azium It still encounters the same error

Comment: Exact error? Can you post the code you had with my suggestion?